# Execute automatically in a loop a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this slider where the gotoslide function changes the slide when the navigation links are pressed.
http://jsfiddle.net/AHYVr/

What is the way to make a loop where the gotoslide function autoruns from 0 to lastone and then goes back to start?

```
var num_slides;
var slides;
var current;
var sa_auto = true;

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  init_slide()
});

function init_slide(){
  slides = jQuery('.slides_container div');
        num_slides = (slides).length;
        pagination = '<ul class="pagination">';
        var i=1;
        jQuery.each(slides, function() {
    pagination += '<li><a href="javascript:gotoslide('+i+')">'+i+'</a></li>';
                i++;
  });
  pagination += '</ul>';
  jQuery(pagination).insertBefore('#slides');


}

function gotoslide(n){
  sa_auto = false;
        showslide(n);
}

function showslide(n){
     current = n;
        var leftpos = (1-n)*700;
        pagination = jQuery('.pagination li')
     pagination.removeClass('current');
        jQuery(pagination[n-1]).addClass("current");
     slides.removeClass('current');
        jQuery(slides[n-1]).addClass("current");
  jQuery('.slides_container').animate({
    left: leftpos
  }, 2000);
}
```

I've tried to make a function that increases the gotoslide parameter by 1 and then use it with a setInterval, but it fails. This is the code:

```
 var t;
        function time (){
         if ( j < num_slides ) {
               show_slide(j++);
         }
        };

        t= setInterval(time, 2000);
        clearInterval(t);
```

Comment: define "it fail's".  Is there an error? does it do nothing? does it do something, just the wrong something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure I 100% understand your question, but I will say that your setInterval will do nothing, because the moment you create it, you cancel it.  Calling `clearInterval(t)` is used when you want an interval to stop, and not fire again.  So, by calling `clearInterval` the very next line after you create it, it will never fire.

If you want to switch slides once every 2 seconds, and start back over again once you reach the end, try something like this:

```
var currentSlide = 0;
var nextSlide = function(){
    currentSlide++
    if(currentSlide >= num_slides){
        currentSlide = 0;
    }

    show_slide(currentSlide);
}

var interval = setInterval(nextSlide, 2000);
```

Comment: Great anwswer, It solves the question. But to get it working in my current script I had to set currentSlide to 1 and change the if(currentSlide >= num_slides +1)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
function init_slide(){
    slides = jQuery('.slides_container div');
    num_slides = (slides).length;
    pagination = '<ul class="pagination">';
    var i=1;
    jQuery.each(slides, function() {
    pagination += '<li><a href="javascript:gotoslide('+i+')">'+i+'</a></li>'; 
            i++;
});
pagination += '</ul>';
jQuery(pagination).insertBefore('#slides');
for ( var n=0;n <num_slides; n++ ){
    gotoslide(n)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added functionality to start and stop the slideshow at whatever slide you want.

```
function initSlideshow( slides, duration, fadeDuration ) {

    var slide = 0;

    function nextSlide( ) {

        if( slide >= slides.length ) slide = 0;

        slides.hide();
        $(slides[slide]).fadeIn( fadeDuration );

        slide++;
        setTimeout( nextSlide, duration );
    }

    function stopSlideshow( num ) {

        slide = ( num >= 0 && num < slides.length ) ? num : 0;
        window.clearTimeout( timer );
        slides.hide();
        $(slides[slide]).fadeIn( fadeDuration );
    }

    function startSlideshow( num ) {

        if( timer ) window.clearTimeout( timer );

        slide = ( num >= 0 && num < slides.length ) ? num : 0;
        timer = setTimeout( nextSlide, 1 );

    }

    var timer = setTimeout( nextSlide, 1 );

    return {
            stop: stopSlideshow,
            start: startSlideshow
    };
}

// example usage
var controller = initSlideshow( $(".slides"), 3000 );
controller.stop( 3 );
controller.start( 1 );
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GApsF/2/)

Answer (score 0):

There we go:

```
for ( var n=1;n <= i; ++n ){
    if(n == i) { gotoslide(1);}
    else {
     gotoslide(n);
    }
}
```

I dont know why you are using var i = 1; imho it is kinda confusing.